# How to check if data exists on server PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to send a string of numbers to the server and split each number. If the number exists on the database assign a "t" value and if it doesn't then assign "f" value.
But for some reason I get t's only.

```
<?php
# get phone from uid
include_once 'utils.php';

$phone = $_GET['phone'] or die("isRegistered: missing phone");
$response = "";
$phonearray = explode(":", $phone);


for ($i = 0; $i<sizeof($phonearray); $i++){

   $result = findRow("phone", $phonearray[i], "user_device") or "true" ;

   if($result == "true")
   {
      $response = $response."t".":";
      $result = "";
   }
   else 
   {
      $response = $response."f".":";
      $result = "";
   }

}

die($response);

?>
```

Comment: Both your if and else conditions set $response to t.

Comment: I'm sorry that was a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's actually a couple problems here.

1. As mentioned in the other answers, you're mistakenly using `'t'` in both branches of your code.
2. You appear to be using the string `"true"` instead of the boolean `true`. While it may appear to work because of the way PHP converts values between types, you're probably actually intending to use `true`, and using the string instead can lead to unexpected behavior later.
3. I don't know what `findRow()` does, but by adding `or true` (or even `or "true"`) to the end of it, `$result` will **always** be `true`.
4. You're using `i` to reference the `$phonearray` instead of `$i`. `i` will generate a PHP warning, and will be interpreted as `"i"` - instead of the value of the `$i` variable.

If you look at this part of your code:

```
$result = findRow("phone", $phonearray[i], "user_device") or "true" ;

if($result == "true")
{
    $response = $response."t".":";
    $result = "";
}
else
{
    $response = $response."t".":";
    $result = "";
}
```

You'll get better results by rewriting it like this:

```
$result = findRow("phone", $phonearray[$i], "user_device");
$response .= ($result ? 't' : 'f') . ':';
```

I'm guessing a bit as to what `findRow()` does since you didn't include anything about it - but I'm assuming it just returns a true/false value.

You'll notice that I've also simplified the entire `if/else` statement down to a couple lines by using the [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) as well.

Comment: the problem is findrow() will go and check in database if the phonenumber exists. and if it does it returns an array of that table data. Now I am only trying to distinguish if that number exists on the database. if it does then i want to assign it a "t" value and if it doesn't then assign a "f" value....but for some reason it gives all true or all false

Comment: The problem was so stupid..$phonearray[i] should be $phonearray[$i]...Thanks for helping. I certainly did learn something.

Comment: @nishan_vodoo Oops - I missed that one. I've updated my answer to include that fix as well (for future reference).

Answer (score 1):

```
if($result == "true")
{
$response = $response."t".":";
$result = "";
}
else 
{
$response = $response."t".":";
$result = "";
}
```

change this part to

```
if($result == "true")
{
$response = $response."t".":";
$result = "";
}
else 
{
$response = $response."f".":";
$result = "";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the fact that `$result` will always be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You have set "t" for both if and else condition.

and do check

```
if(isset($_GET['phone']))
```

Comment: This doesn't address the fact that `$result` will always be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($result == "true")
{
$response = $response."t".":";
$result = "";
}
else 
{
$response = $response."t".":";
$result = "";
}
```

change this part to

```
if($result == 'true')
{
$response = $response.'t:';
$result = '';
}
else 
{
$response = $response.'f:';
$result = '';
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17540362/398242

Comment: @WesleyMurch Check the difference.

Comment: This doesn't address the fact that `$result` will always be `true`.